# Gradleのビルドエラー『Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution…』

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

環境：Windows 10　Java 1.8.0_281　Spring Tools Suite 4.10.0

SpringのstarterでGradleプロジェクトを作成した後、build.gradle に編集を加えると下記のビルドエラーとなります。
このエラーの対処方法をご教示頂けますと大変助かります。

```
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip'.
The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
It won't be possible to reconnect to this daemon. Context mismatch: 
Java home is different.
Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_281,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\cycom\_gradle\gradle-7.0.2-bin\gradle-7.0.2\daemon,pid=4288,idleTimeout=null,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xms256m,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-31j,-Duser.country=JP,-Duser.language=ja,-Duser.variant]
Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=846d1527-9f41-4aa4-97a5-92c27366195e,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\cycom\_gradle\gradle-7.0.2-bin\gradle-7.0.2\daemon,pid=2868,idleTimeout=10800000,priority=NORMAL,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xms256m,-Xmx512m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-31j,-Duser.country=JP,-Duser.language=ja,-Duser.variant]
```

build.gradleを編集したい内容は例えばdependenciesに下記を追加する、などですが、build.gradleを編集してリビルドを行うと上記のエラーとなります。

```
　compile('org.lognet:grpc-spring-boot-starter:${grpcStarterVersion}')
```

上記は、JAVA_HOMEがうまく適用できていない類の既知のエラーらしいことは分かってきたのですが、具体的な解決方法が分かっていません。
参照URL：　https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/1050

下記などを試みましたが上記のエラーは回避できていません：
　・ユーザ環境変数に明示的にJAVA_HOMEを設定する
　・STSのGradle設定でGradleバージョンおよびJAVAホームを明示する

設定ファイルなどは下記となっています（starterで作成したままの状態）
gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'kikan_grpc.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: エラーメッセージとして出力されている、"Wanted"と"Actual"を比較してみるとわかりますが、`javaHome`に設定されているpathが異なります(片方はjre, 他方はjdk)。ので、おそらくどこかで設定を誤っているのではないかと思われます。